# Possibly an unnecessary assumption in Royden 4Ed. Question 5.11

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm reading Royden's *Real Analysis* 4th edition, there is a problem given by 5.11. I found a proof but it seems that this proof doesn't need one of the assumptions in the problem, which is *$E$ has finite measure*.

The problem is:

> Assume $E$ has finite measure. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ and $f$ a measurable function on $E$ for which $f$ and each $f_n$ is finite a.e. on $E$. Prove that $\{f_n\}\to f$ in measure on $E$ if and only if every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has in turn a further subsequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$.

My proof is:

Suppose $\{f_n\}\to f$ in measure, then any subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ also converges to $f$ in measure. By Riesz's theorem, this subsequence has a subsequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$.

To prove the converse, we argue by contradiction. When $\{f_n\}$ doesn't converge to $f$ in measure, there are $\eta_0$ and $\varepsilon_0$ such that for every $N>0$, there is an $n_0 > N$ for which $m(\{x \in E \mid |f_{n_0} - f| > \eta_0\})\geq\varepsilon_0$.

Therefore we can find a strictly increasing sequences of natural numbers $\{n_k\}$ for which
    \begin{equation}
   m(\{x \in E \mid |f_{n_k} - f| > \eta_0\}) \geq \varepsilon_0\text{, for all }k
   \label{eq:ch4.11}
  \end{equation}
Then by the assumption, there is a further subsequence of $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$. However, this contradicts the above equation.  $\square$

Note that *a.e.* is the abbreviation of *almost everywhere* and Riesz's theorem is:

> If $\{f_n\}\to f$ in measure on $E$, then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $f$.

Is there something wrong in my proof, or the assumption of *$E$ has finite measure* used implicitly but I do not notice that, or this assumption unnecessary?

Comment: "However, this contradicts the above". Does it? Why? If $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1)}$, then $\lambda(\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert > 1/2\}) = 1$ for all $n$, but $f_n \to 0$ pointwise.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oooops. So I think when the convergence is uniform the result is right, and we need use Egorov's theorem to it, therefore $E$ must be finite?

Comment: Sort of. If $m$ is $\sigma$-finite, the "every subsequence has …" is [equivalent to _local_ convergence in measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Properties). Assuming finiteness avoids the local/global distinction and further problems. (If $m$ isn't $\sigma$-finite, you generally don't get even local convergence in measure.)